# Python Web Scraping with Multiple URLs + merge datas

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

What I'm trying to do is

- Take multiple URLs.
- Take h2 text in every URL.
- Merge h2 texts and then write csv.

In this code, I did:
Take one URL. Take h2 text in URL.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

page_url = "https://example.com/ekonomi/20200108/"

#i am trying to do | urls = ['https://example.com/ekonomi/20200114/', 'https://example.com/ekonomi/20200113/', 'https://example.com/ekonomi/20200112/', 'https://example.com/ekonomi/20200111/]

uClient = uReq(page_url)

page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")
uClient.close()

# finds each product from the store page
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "b-plainlist__info"})

out_filename = "output.csv"

headers = "title \n"


f = open(out_filename, "w")
f.write(headers)

container = containers[0]

for container in containers:
    title = container.h2.get_text()

    f.write(title.replace(",", " ") + "\n")

f.close()  # Close the file
```

Comment: I think Item Pipeline from Scrapy could help you https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-a-json-file

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: @alec_djinn I can't take multiple URLs.

Comment: well, you need to 1) set up a for loop that iterates over your list of urls `for page_url in urls:`; and 2) you'll want to append them to your file not overwrite after each iteration `f = open(out_filename, "a")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided your iteration through the `containers` is correct, this should work:

You want to iterate through the urls. Each url will grab the title, and append it into a list. Then just create a series with that list and write to csv with Pandas:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import pandas as pd


urls = ['https://example.com/ekonomi/20200114/', 'https://example.com/ekonomi/20200113/', 'https://example.com/ekonomi/20200112/', 'https://example.com/ekonomi/20200111/']

titles = []
for page_url in urls:
    uClient = uReq(page_url)

    page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")
    uClient.close()

    # finds each product from the store page
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "b-plainlist__info"})

    for container in containers:
        titles.append(container.h2.get_text())

df = pd.DataFrame(titles, columns=['title'])
df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```